# Download Failed - No file. React JS, Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, download, filepath

I have created an application where I use React JS as frontend language to upload the file and Spring boot as backend service to save the file into the local machine directory.

Eg: My path where the file I saved file in ubuntu is like /home/user/resume/resume.pdf

I'm trying to download the file from react js by the above path. When I click it shows failed and when I check the url it appends localhost like this http://localhost:3000//home/user/resume/resume.pdf.

I use this code

```
<a href={candidate.fileUrl} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" download>{candidate.fileName}</a>
```

candidate.fileUrl = /home/user/resume/resume.pdf but it shows onclick like this http://localhost:3000/home/user/resume/resume.pdf

Can anyone help me why it appends localhost before my path which results in downloading failed?

Answer (score 0):

When you put in a tag the href parameter and you precede this with "/", the browser will concatenate this compliment as PROTOCOL://SERVER:PORT/

Well, it's how browsers works, so if you don't wanna this, you can append all the path like: "file:///home/user/resume/resume.pdf"

Comment: Somehow it's working now but not fully. When I click it does nothing. when I copy link address and manually paste on new tab then it opens the file on browser.